# how to create a view of self join in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

While trying to create a view of following query, I get stuck with an error. I have a table named `student` and i want a view named `birthday_twins` which contain names and dob of birthday twins.

```
CREATE VIEW birthday_twins AS
SELECT s.student_name,p.student_name,s.date_of_birth 
FROM student s,student p 
WHERE s.student_id <> p.student_id AND s.date_of_birth=p.date_of_birth 
GROUP BY s.date_of_birth;
```

> Error Code : 1060 Duplicate column name 'student_name'

I am completely new to sql. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Your query makes no sense -- it wouldn't even run in the more recent versions of MySQL (or almost any other database).  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pairs of people born on the same day, then use:

```
CREATE VIEW birthday_twins AS
    SELECT s1.student_name as name1,
           s2.student_name as name2,
           s1.date_of_birth 
    FROM student s1 JOIN
         student s2
         ON s1.student_id < s2.student_id AND 
            s1.date_of_birth = s2.date_of_birth ;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- No aggregation is necessary.
- Columns returned by a view must have different names, so use `as` to rename the columns.
- Use `<` rather than `<>` so you don't get reversed pairs (unless you want to list pairs twice).

Answer (score 2):

you need to give aliases to column names so that view can differentiate field names. i.e.:

```
CREATE VIEW birthday_twins AS 
SELECT s.student_name name1,p.student_name name2,s.date_of_birth 
FROM student s,student p 
WHERE s.student_id <> p.student_id 
AND s.date_of_birth=p.date_of_birth 
GROUP BY s.date_of_birth;
```